Неправильно работает функция с С строкой
Задания- Функция принимает на вход C строчку. В результате она должна создать и вернуть новую строку, содержащую все символы, которые в этой строке встречаются только один раз.
Мой код
сhar* findOneCString(const char* str)
{
   const size_t size = strlen(str);
   char* strNew = new char[size + 1];
   int num = 0;

   for (size_t index = 0; index < size; ++index) 
   {
      for (size_t j = size; j > index; --j)
      {
         if (str[index] == str[j])
         { 
          
         }
         else 
         {
            strNew[num] = str[index];
            ++num;
        }
      }
   }
 strNew[num] = '\0';
 return strNew;
}

У меня ошибки возникли и я не понимаю почему(

утечка памяти
записываются значения в новый массив пару раз.

Я понимаю что для большинства эта задачка легкая.. Но я не могу понять где я не так делаю

Вы делаете совсем не то, что требуется. А именно, вы добавляете символ в новую строку каждый раз, когда в просматриваемом "хвосте" строки встречается символ не равный ему. Протестируйте на каком-нибудь большом тексте и распечатайте num в конце (и вы ужаснетесь). Попробуйте самый очевидный алгоритм -- для каждого символа подсчитайте (просматривая всю строку во вложенном цикле) сколько раз он встретился. Если ровно один, то добавляйте в новую строку. Более эффективный (для длинных строк) алгоритм потребует массив счетчиков, размером 255 в котором вы используете символ строки как индекс.

"1. утечка памяти" - если вручную выделяете память на куче (char* strNew = new char[size + 1];), то и удалять нужно тоже самому (через delete)

Главный вопрос, никак у вас не указанный: должны ли в новой строке символы идти в том же порядке, что и первый раз в исходной строке? Из Hello должно получаться обязательно Helo или можно olHe?

@Harry  новая строка, содержит все символы, которые в старой строке встречаются только один раз.  Например Hello - Heo

Главное - порядок. Просто простейшее решение - массив из 256 чисел :) Но порядок при этом будет нарушен.

Если выделяем память через new [], то и освобождаем через delete[]. А вообще, возвращать указатель на где-то выделенную память - не самая хорошая идея. Гораздо лучше, когда тот, кто выделяет память, тот её и освобождает. А в функцию можно передать указатель на уже подготовленный буфер.
Выделять под результат strlen(str) + 1 символов нет необходимости. Больше 256 всё равно не получится.
#include <iostream>

void findOneCString(const char* str, char* res) {
    int counter[256]{};

    for (auto ptr = (unsigned char*)(str); *ptr != '\0'; ++ptr) {
        ++counter[*ptr];
    }

    int pos = 0;;
    for (int ch = 0; ch < 256; ++ch) {
        if (counter[ch] == 1) {
            res[pos] = ch;
            ++pos;
        }
    }
    res[pos] = '\0';
}

int main()
{
    //if (!setlocale(LC_ALL, "")) return 1; // опционально

    char buf[256];
    findOneCString("ыфхщHello World!\nqwertyuiop", buf);
    std::cout << buf;

    std::cout << "\n";
    system("pause");
}

Вывод:

 !HWdipqtuwyфхщы

Если нужно сохранить порядок символов:
#include <iostream>

void findOneCString(const char* str, char* res) {
    int counter[256]{};

    for (auto ptr = (unsigned char*)(str); *ptr != '\0'; ++ptr) {
        ++counter[*ptr];
    }

    int pos = 0;;
    for (auto ptr = (unsigned char*)(str); *ptr != '\0'; ++ptr) {
        if (counter[*ptr] == 1) {
            counter[*ptr] = 0;
            res[pos] = *ptr;
            ++pos;
        }
    }
    res[pos] = '\0';
}

int main()
{
    //if (!setlocale(LC_ALL, "")) return 1; // опционально

    char buf[256];
    findOneCString("ыфхщHello World!\nqwertyuiop", buf);
    std::cout << buf;

    std::cout << "\n";
    system("pause");
}

Вывод:
ыфхщH Wd!
qwtyuip


Эмм, я удалил, предыдущий ответ. Думал, начисленные за него баллы спишутся. Наверное нужно было просто исправить его?

Да, в вашем случае скорее нужно было просто исправить тот ответ, а не давать новый ответ, ведь костяк то решения не поменялся, просто доработка деталей. Но теперь то что уж. А два одинаковых ответа тоже не нужно, конечно. Если уж дали новый ответ, то старый такой же логично удалить.

Ага, понял. Буду иметь в виду

Если  на вашем компе char знаковый, то для символов от 0x80 до 0xff  индекс массива counter *ptr будет отрицательным (со всеми вытекающими...). Поэтому всюду пишите counter[(unsigned char)(*ptr)]

Да, спасибо. Исправил

Я маленько исправил ваш код, главным образом его внутренний цикл:
char* findOneCString(const char* str)
{
   const size_t size = strlen(str);
   char* strNew = new char[size + 1];
   strNew[0] = '\n';                         // сначала пустая строка
   int num = 0;

   for (size_t index = 0; index < size; ++index) 
   {
      bool no_repeat = true;                 // очередной символ еще не повторился
      for (size_t j = 0; j < strlen(strNew); ++j)
      {
         if (str[index] == strNew[j])
         { 
             no_repeat = false;              // когда он первый раз повторился,
             break;                          // это хватит
         }
      }
      if (no_repeat)
      {
          strNew[num] = str[index];
          ++num;
          strNew[num] = '\0';
      }
   }
   return strNew;
}


Tест:
cout << findOneCString("Abracadabra!");

выводит

Abracd!    



Объяснение:
Не надо сравнивать символы заданной строки (параметра) с символами тот самой строки.
Лучше их сравнивать с символами новой строки strNew, которую сначала сделаем пустой, и затем будем в нее постепенно добавлять символы из строки str, которых в ней затем нет.
